# Portable way of sending 64-bit variable through POSIX socket

Tags: c, sockets, 64-bit, posix, portability

I'm designing custom network protocol and I need to send [`uint64_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html#tag_13_47_03_01) variable (representing file's length in bytes) through [`socket`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/socket.3p.html) in [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Portability) and [POSIX-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) manner.

Unfortunately [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html#tag_13_47_03_01) says that integer types with width 64 are **not guaranteed** to exist:

> If an implementation provides integer types with width 64 that meet these requirements, then the following types are required: `int64_t` `uint64_t`

What's more there is no POSIX-compliant equivalent of [`htonl`, `htons`, `ntohl`, `ntohs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/htonl.html) (note that [`bswap_64`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bswap_64.3.html) [is **not**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022552/is-there-any-standard-htonl-like-function-for-64-bits-integers-in-c) POSIX-compliant).

What is the best practice to send 64-bit variable through socket?

Comment: Specify the byte order, and send it byte-wise. The receiver has to follow the documented byte-order if the receiver want to use the value. And if the receiver is on a system without built-in support for 64-bit integers, there are libraries to use which can handle it. In short: Be well-documented in what you do, and let the other end worry about compatibility with you.

Comment: I think that using library for systems that doesn't support 64-bit integers is overkill. I'm writing protocol implementation in C which is quite [low-level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language) and I want to cleverly handle this situation using [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and (possibly) macros.

Comment: The question is not really about sockets but about serializing and unserializing 64 bit integers to binary in a portable way. It does not matter if this is done to send it over a socket, store it in a file or whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portable C binary serialization primitives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500425/portable-c-binary-serialization-primitives). Also [Is there any “standard” htonl-like function for 64 bits integers in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022552/is-there-any-standard-htonl-like-function-for-64-bits-integers-in-c)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I linked your [second link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022552/is-there-any-standard-htonl-like-function-for-64-bits-integers-in-c) in my original question. The [first link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500425/portable-c-binary-serialization-primitives) doesn't answer my question. The question has socket context because I hoped that it is easier for you to answer what is best practice for handling this situation in socket-related programming. BTW: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073667/where-to-find-the-complete-definition-of-off-t-type).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809902/64-bit-ntohl-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just apply `htonl()` twice, of course:

```
const uint64_t x = ...
const uint32_t upper_be = htonl(x >> 32);
const uint32_t lower_be = htonl((uint32_t) x);
```

This will give you two 32-bit variables containing big-endian versions of the upper and lower 32-bit halves of the 64-bit variable `x`.

If you are strict POSIX, you can't use `uint64_t` since it's not guaranteed to exist. Then you can do something like:

```
typedef struct {
 uint32_t upper;
 uint32_t lower;
} my_uint64;
```

And just `htonl()` those directly, of course.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is a macro... mine looks similar to this and checks for local byte ordering before deciding how to handle the byte ordering:

```
// clang-format off
#if !defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__) && !defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__)
#   if defined(__has_include)
#     if __has_include(<endian.h>)
#      include <endian.h>
#     elif __has_include(<sys/endian.h>)
#      include <sys/endian.h>
#     endif
#   endif
#   if !defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN__) &&                                             \
                (defined(__BIG_ENDIAN__) || __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__)
#      define __BIG_ENDIAN__
#      define bswap64(i)   (i) // do nothing
#   else
#      define __LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#      define bswap64(i) ((((i)&0xFFULL) << 56) | (((i)&0xFF00ULL) << 40) |     \
          (((i)&0xFF0000ULL) << 24) | (((i)&0xFF000000ULL) << 8) |              \
          (((i)&0xFF00000000ULL) >> 8) | (((i)&0xFF0000000000ULL) >> 24) |      \
          (((i)&0xFF000000000000ULL) >> 40) |                                   \
          (((i)&0xFF00000000000000ULL) >> 56)) 
#   endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a POSIX platform with C99 or greater, `{u,}int64_t` are not required to exist but `{u,}int_{least,fast}64_t` are.

Additionally, [POSIX requires `{u,}int{8,16,32}_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html).

So what you can do is:

```
#include <stdint.h>

//host-to-network (native endian to big endian)
void hton64(unsigned char *B, uint_least64_t X)
{

    B[0]=X>>56&0xFF;
    B[1]=X>>48&0xFF;
    B[2]=X>>40&0xFF;
    B[3]=X>>32&0xFF;
    B[4]=X>>24&0xFF;
    B[5]=X>>16&0xFF;
    B[6]=X>>8&0xFF;
    B[7]=X>>0&0xFF;
}

//network-to-host (big endian to native endian)
uint_least64_t ntoh64(unsigned char const *B)
{
    return (uint_least64_t)B[0]<<56|
           (uint_least64_t)B[1]<<48|
           (uint_least64_t)B[2]<<40|
           (uint_least64_t)B[3]<<32|
           (uint_least64_t)B[4]<<24|
           (uint_least64_t)B[5]<<16|
           (uint_least64_t)B[6]<<8|
           (uint_least64_t)B[7]<<0;
}
```

If the machine has `uint64_t`, then `uint_least64_t` will be (due to requirements imposed by the C standard) identical to `uint64_t`.

If it doesn't, then `uint_least64_t` might not be 2's-complement or it might have more value bits (I have no idea if there are such architectures), but regardless of that, the above routines will send or receive exactly (if there's more) 64 lower-order bits of it (to or from a buffer).

(Anyway, this solutionshould be good as a generic backend, but if you want to be slightly more optimal, then you can try to first detect your endianness and do nothing if it's a big endian platform; if it's a little endian and `sizeof(uint_least64_t)*CHAR_BIT==64`, then if you can detect you have byteswap.h with bswap_64, then you should use that as it's likely to compile down to a single instruction. If all else fails, I'd use something like the above.)